# Why can't I run this tcp client socket code without \n?

Tags: java, string, sockets, tcpsocket

I was trying this code. it works fine but if I remove `\n` in `String str` it doesn't work I mean It was able to compile without `\n` but it didn't give me output.

```
public class Test {
    // Use try-with-resources to close a socket.
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int c;
        // Create a socket connected to internic.net, port 43. Manage this
        // socket with a try-with-resources block.
        try (Socket s = new Socket("whois.internic.net", 43)) {
            // Obtain input and output streams.
            InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
            // Construct a request string.
            String str = (args.length == 0 ? "MHProfessional.com" : args[0]) + "\n"; // <- herer
            // Convert to bytes.
            byte buf[] = str.getBytes();
            // Send request.
            out.write(buf);
            // Read and display response.
            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) c);
            }
        }
        // The socket is now closed.
    }
}
```

Comment: The server is probably using the `\n` as a indicator to term the amount of content it should read

Answer (score 1):

The server you're talking to reads data up until an end-of-line (\n) character -- that's just the way it works, but it's far from unusual. It's possible that other end-of-line sequences will be accepted as well.

The server has to have *some* way to know the client has finished sending data. It will probably know if the client closes its connection, but by then it's too late to respond to the client.